# MultiBinding Fallback value on unsetvalue

Tags: wpf, converters, multibinding, fallback

I'm looking for a way to specify a fallback value if any of the bindings within a multibinding fail.

Here is the case where the binding succeeds(i.e, A and B are valid paths)

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{local:MultiConverter}">
    <Binding Path="A"/>
    <Binding Path="B"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Here, is a case where it fails(path to 'B' is broken)

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{local:MultiConverter}">
    <Binding Path="A"/>
    <Binding Path="Bb"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

which passes in a value of {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue} for value[1] of the converter. I was hoping I could do something like the following :

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{local:MultiConverter}" FallbackValue="Egg">
    <Binding Path="A"/>
    <Binding Path="Bb"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

but, unfortunately, the convertor is still called with the unset value.

Whilst I'm aware that you can do the following

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{local:MultiConverter}">
    <Binding Path="A"/>
    <Binding Path="Bb" FallbackValue="Egg"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

It's not what I want. I want to specify the fallback for the entire multibinding to be X, if any of the subbindings fail. I don't want to have to specify a fallback for each component.

Currently, I'm resorting to the following, ... but I'd like to specify the fallback on the multibinding, not the converter.

```
public class MultiConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Any(e => e == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue))
        {
            return "failed!";
        }
        return values[0].ToString() + values[1].ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object values, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use the [TargetNullValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx) to return `null` from the converter instead of the `"failed!"`

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{local:MultiConverter}" TargetNullValue="Failed!">
    <Binding Path="A"/>
    <Binding Path="Bb" />
</MultiBinding>
```

This way you do the check in the converter and if the converter returns `null` because of any binding error's your result would pick the `TargetNullvalue`

Comment: But this still means I have to be checking for unset values in the MultiConverter. Which isn't a massive problem as I can just put that code in a common base class for all my converters, but it seems like something that is already being done, and that I'm just using it incorrectly.

Comment: @pastillman yes you do need to check it in the converter since your checking it "globally" there for all the incoming `values[i]`. Else as you mentioned you can do it on a per binding basis or use a `PriorityBinding` if you do not want to pass in invalid binding's at all. Having the Converter return null is perfectly valid since it also helps with localisation where you have strings referenced from xaml directly.